# How to prevent buttons from resizing when I scroll tableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview with buttons which I resize with the below code to fit their labels:

```swift
class ResizableButtons: UIButton {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
          let labelSize = titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)) ?? .zero
          let desiredButtonSize = CGSize(width: labelSize.width + titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right, height: labelSize.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom)
          return desiredButtonSize
      }
}
```

[image][image]

It works pretty well.

The problem occurs when I try to scroll tableview down and up.

[image] [image]

As you can see from the snapshots, buttons get resized. And it seems to happen only after I click on some button and start to scroll. If I scroll without clicking the sizes remains ok.

I believe the problem lays in how I set titles to the buttons. I do it with the following code :

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//Every second row has a button.
     if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell") as! ReusableCell
     cell.button.setTitle(textAndButtonsArray[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

//Checking if button was pressed before
     if pressedButtons.contains(indexPath.row) {
         print("Text for selected button at indexpath \(indexPath.row) is \(cell.button.titleLabel?.text)")
     }
}
```

So if I print into the console indexPath and textLabel for pressed buttons, it gives me correct indexPath. But the textLabel displayed in the console is from a different button. From the one that is 10 rows later than the actual pressed one.

[image]

Any ideas how I could fix it?

P.S. Don't pay attention to text and labels on the buttons, I wrote whatever came to my mind first :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize your cell or buttons inside `willDisplayCell` and reset the button size in `prepareForReuse`. Call inside `intrinsicContentSize` `button.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found a solution. In the part where I resize the buttons, I need to change `titleLabel` to `currentTitle`. So it looks like this:

```swift
class ResizableButtons: UIButton {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let label = currentTitle
        titleLabel?.text = label
        let labelSize = titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)) ?? .zero
        let desiredButtonSize = CGSize(width: labelSize.width + titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right, height: labelSize.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom)
        return desiredButtonSize
}

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel!.frame.size.width
    }
}
```

Not sure why is that. But it seems that XCode is updating labels on the buttons with some sort of delay. And `button.titleLabel` doesn't always match with `button.currentTitle`

Also last few lines with `layoutSubviews()` seems to matter.